# How do I truncate text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I truncate the text inside my anchor tag?

From

```
<a href=''>lorem ipsum</a>
```

to

```
<a href=''>lorem...</a>
```

with a maximum length of **57 characters plus the ellipsis**.

Comment: you want to short or sort?

Comment: I think you need to reword or explain a little more on what you want.

Comment: i want short the characters of the link "a"
for exemple <a href=''>lorem ipsum is </a>  to <a href=''> lorem...</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do this with plain css!**
html

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="truncate">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Foo Bar Baz Qux Quux Waffle</a>
```

css

```
.truncate {
  width: 100px; // for example
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**or**

you could use js; here's my favorite implementation:

```
  var $shortlink = $('a.truncate');

  function trunc(str, n) {
    return str.substr(0,n-1)+'&hellip;'
  }

  var txt = $shortlink.text(t);
  $shortlink.html(trunc(txt, 40));
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery can use `text(function)`.

```
var txtMax = 60;
$('a').text(function(_, txt){
  txt = $.trim(txt);
   return txt.length > txtMax ? txt.slice(0,txtMax -3)+'...' : txt;     
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ty5Lov1x/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: not the words 
i need to short the characters 
like the maximum characters is 57 +'...'

Comment: that is not a detailed enough explanation...shorten by what amount or what limits?

Comment: i need to short the characters like the maximum characters is 57 +'...'

Comment: Your example doesn't show that though. Maybe give a exact example of what you need.

Comment: Updated for length. Please be more precise with questions in the future. Include full details of what your issue is and accurate examples

Comment: this is the link 
<a id="short" href="#">There's strong evidence that taking part in sport improves health</a>
i went to transforme it to <a id="short" href="#">There's strong evidence that taking part...</a>

Comment: OK, so use an ID selector `$('#short')` and ID's can only be used once in page

Answer (score 0):

Give the element an ID, then (IE9 plus):

```
var maxLength = 57,
    el = document.getElementById('short'),
    existing = el.textContent,
    replacement = existing.slice(0,maxLength) + '...';
el.textContent = replacement;
```

You can also use CSS:

```
#short {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You will need to check browser support though. The first method is not safe for multi-byte character-based languages either (like Chinese).

Check out:

http://jsfiddle.net/1ugurr7w/

Answer (score 0):

i use this feed

```
$(".news .widget-content").each(function(){var e=$(this).text();if(e.match("recent")){$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=10",type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){var t="";var n="<ul>";for(var r=0;r<e.feed.entry.length;r++){for(var i=0;i<e.feed.entry[r].link.length;i++){if(e.feed.entry[r].link[i].rel=="alternate"){t=e.feed.entry[r].link[i].href;break}}var s=e.feed.entry[r].title.$t;var o=e.feed.entry[r].category[0].term;n+='<li><a href="/search/label/'+o+'" class="post-tag">'+o+'</a><h3 class="recent-title"><a id="short" href="'+t+'">'+s+"</a></h3></li>"}n+="</ul>";$(".news .widget-content").each(function(){$(this).html(n);$(this).prev("h2").prepend('<i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i>');$(this).removeClass("widget-content").addClass("layout-content");$(this).find("ul").newsTicker({row_height: 50, max_rows: 1, duration: 4000, prevButton: $('.but-left'), nextButton: $('.but-right') });$("p.trans").each(function(){var e=$(this).text();var t=$(this).attr("data-tran");$("#pages-wrapper *").replaceText(e,t)})})}})}else{$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+e+"?alt=json-in-script&max-results=10",type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){var t="";var n="<ul>";for(var r=0;r<e.feed.entry.length;r++){for(var i=0;i<e.feed.entry[r].link.length;i++){if(e.feed.entry[r].link[i].rel=="alternate"){t=e.feed.entry[r].link[i].href;break}}var s=e.feed.entry[r].title.$t;var o=e.feed.entry[r].category[0].term;n+='<li><a href="/search/label/'+o+'" class="post-tag">'+o+'</a><h3 class="recent-title"><a id="short" href="'+t+'">'+s+"</a></h3></li>"}n+="</ul>";$(".news .widget-content").each(function(){$(this).html(n);$(this).removeClass("widget-content").addClass("layout-content");$(this).find("ul").newsTicker({ row_height: 50, max_rows: 1, duration: 4000, prevButton: $('.but-left'), nextButton: $('.but-right') });$("p.trans").each(function(){var e=$(this).text();var t=$(this).attr("data-tran");$("#pages-wrapper *").replaceText(e,t)})})}})}});
```